# How to fetch data from given graph URL in facebook graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is the Javascript:

The purpose of this code is to get Number of user's posts in last 3 Months.

```
FB.api('/me/photos?fields=created_time&since=2013-03-28', function(response){
        dLen = response.data.length;
        if(!response.paging.next){
            dLenContent = "<div><span class='left'>"+i+++".</span><span class='mid'>  Number of times tagged in photos: </span><span class='right'>"+dLen+"</span></div>";
        }
        else{
            nextURL = response.paging.next;
            while(nextURL){
                graphURL = nextURL;
                ---------------------------------------
                ---How to fetch data from next page(graphURL)?---
                ---------------------------------------
                dLen = dLen + response.data.length;
                nextURL = response.paging.next;
            }
        }
        pInfo = document.getElementById("personalInfo");
        pInfo.innerHTML += dLenContent;
    });
```

In case there is next page, the else part of the code will be executed.
In that else part, I have written one while loop which will be active until the is next page in the object we get.

I want to know get data of "response.paging.next"?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a 2 steps thing

1. Parse the next/previous URL from the response. You can do it yourself or [one of the many libraries](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)
2. With the timestamp parsed, just call your function recursively and "since" in the Graph URL.

   function getFBData(date) {
       FB.api('/me/photos?fields=created_time&since=' + date, function(response){
          var pager = "parse the paging data from facebook"
          getFBData(pager);
       });
   }